# Why was the Shinobi War started?

Tags: naruto

Why was the Shinobi War started if

> Kyuubi chakra was all that was needed? Without Naruto (Kyuubi) and Killer B (Hachibi) being captured, the eternal genjutsu (Moon Eye) was initiated by Tobi/Madara. The reason being they could do it, is because they had one of Hachibi's tentacles (courtesy: Sasuke) and Kyuubi's chakra (Gold and Silver brothers). So which means all they needed was a sample of Kyuubi chakra (since all 7 Tailed Beasts were sealed, it was powerful enough to begin Moon Eye, also they had Hachibi's tentacle). Why did Tobi initiate the war if he could have collected Kyuubi chakra somehow? If Tobi knew about it earlier, could the war have been avoided?

His ambition could have been achieved without any war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim was to revive the Ten-Tails in its prime and that is why they wanted to seal both *Kyuubi* and *Gyuuki* completely too. But after the *Edo Tensei* was released by *Itachi*, *Obito* lost all the revived Jinchuuriki's of the other 7 tailed beasts. Though he had them sealed, he couldn't use them in the battle anymore and facing both Naruto and Killer B alone would have been difficult for him.

Thus he decided to revive the Ten-Tails with just the 7 beasts and the little chakra samples of Kyuubi and Gyuuki he already had(sealed Kinkaku, Ginkaku and a piece of the tail of Gyuuki) so that he could become its Jinchuuriki and complete the *Eye of the Moon plan.*

Here is a sequence of images from the Manga, which will help you understand the whole thing better. Most of it is from the [Manga Episode 594](http://www.mangahit.com/naruto/594/7), and is finally out in the anime too, Naruto Shippuden Episode 341.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 5]
[image: Image 6]

Comment: while i feel that the answer is an appropriate one, adding refereneces to manga chapter and/or images or other external reliable sources could make the answer much better. :)

Comment: @debal - Done! :)

Comment: @R.J, while I feel the answer is perfect now, adding manga images will make it a spoiler .. rather please provide a link to those images (specifying it would lead to spoiler). Also please use `>!` to apply spoilerproof on corresponding statements..

Comment: Thanks for the nice and clear answer.. I will accept it after I'm allowed to..

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' - The last episode of Anime showed Obito performing the seal-type action for revival of Ten-Tails. So the text looks fine, but I guess the Manga images would be a spoiler. The problem here is, within 4 weeks, all this is gonna come on anime anyways. Anyways, will keep the relevant stuff and make the other stuffs as spoiler proof.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' - Whenever this episode is aired in the anime, I just need to add a few exclamation marks, and that's enough to make the answer like before! :)

Comment: @R.J, Appreciated.. The reason is, anime.Stackexchange is very strict about spoiler-proofing, I didn't want your answer get downvotes because of that.. Moreover, it would take more time than expected for anime makers to telecast these.. you see they just love fillers ;)

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' - Magically, the anime guys took pity on us and released it this week! :) Episode 341 was worth the watch.

Comment: hahaha :D cheers for that ..